# Are there built-in issue tracking and task management in IDEs that integrate into SourceForge, Google Code, etc?

Tags: ide, issue-tracking

This question may not be exactly programming related, but this is about development. I have been trying to find IDEs that support JIRA/Bugzilla so that I could simply integrate the IDE with SourceForge. I do not like to refresh my browser to see issues, bug reports, security problems, etc. I would like to send issues, resolve issues, right from the IDE. I am currently developing with NetBeans, but I see no ways of integrating into any of the services provided by SourceForge. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Eclipse's Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) has a load of free connectors to hook into practically any issue tracking system around. I'm using it with Fogbugz and it Just Works. Really awesome software.